# Set State of Switch in RecyclerView Based on Comparison of Values in an ArrayList<String> and a TextView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that displays a list of applications currently installed on the device. Each row includes the name of the application, its package name, and a switch. When the Switch isChecked, the package name is added to an ArrayList. If the user clicks back into that Activity, I need to repopulate the list and set the state of Switches based on what was previously added to the ArrayList.

The overall idea I have to achieve this is to do a comparison of the package names in the RecyclerView to those stored in the ArrayList, and when there is a match the Switch for that row needs to be set to checked.

I am not sure how to best accomplish this. I think it needs to be done in the Activity using the Adapter, not the Adapter itself. I know it is also going to involve a loop.

Anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

OP (30 Jan 2018): https://coderanch.com/t/690164/mobile/Set-Switch-State-Based-Comparison

Answer (score 1):

You could implement it like this:
Your Adapter gets handed in a list of ViewModels that have

```
String displayName;
String identifier;
boolean isChecked;
```

Your Adapter could notify a Listener

```
interface AdapterListener {
    void onSwitchChanged(ViewModel viewModel);
}
```

Ýour listener could be a Presenter or a ViewModel. Your listener might also manage all your ViewModels (as he may have created or got them from another instance). When you need your ArrayList, you can

a) instantiate it on demand (iterate your ViewModels and extract those that are checked)

b) your Listener can manage the List directly. You can make a `List<String>` and add / remove the app-identifiers. You do not need to loop through, you can just call `list.remove("THEAPPIDKEY");` and the list will correctly delete the key you wanted to remove.

Comment: The loop seems necessary, since the packages displayed in the RecyclerView are subject to change (if the user uninstalls an app). That's why I was suggesting doing a comparison of the packages displayed in the RecyclerView to those in the ArrayList of selected packages. Otherwise, isn't there the chance of a nullPointerException if the app tries to set a switch for a package that doesn't exist?

Comment: The module that gives the list to your recyclerview, as for example the presenter or viemodel, is in charge of changing the list. In case the user uninstalls an app, there might be a listener (Broadcast Receiver or sth like this) the Viewmodel / presenter is listening to. When the presenter gets notified, that an app was uninstalled, it can remove the entry in the list but it also has to tell the recyclerview to remove the item. No NPE

Answer (score 0):

I usually have the Adapter class as a sub class within my Activity class. This way, the Adapter can access fields belonging to the Activity.

In any case, the adapter has to know about the values it should show as 'switched on'. So, if you have a separate class for the Adapter you'll need to pass your ArrayList to the adapter (e.g. via its Constructor).

Comment: This will lead to bloated Activities; I do not recommend doing this. Extract your adapter in another file, it helps keeping the code clean.

Comment: In my recent research regarding my issue, I have seen numerous instances of people sub-classing their adapters. However, as @FlorianHansen has suggested, I find that practice to create "bloated code." I use a separate class to keep things clean.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a custom class and create an array list from that. When that list is passed to the adapter you can pull the value back out.

```
class PhoneItem{
boolean switchState;
String blah;
String foo;
}
//get the data from the originating class
ArrayList<phoneItem>phones = new Arraylist();
mMySwitch.setChecked(phones.get(viewHolderCount).switchState);
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but as I have suggested to Florian Hansen, there needs to be a comparison done, since the packages displayed in the RecyclerView might change (if the user uninstalls an app). If my Activity attempts to set a Switch that doesn't exist, it will throw a NullPointerException. Correct?